# open links from History page in new tab

Tags: google-chrome

Each entry in the History page of Google Chrome is a link that will take users to that page if they click on it. I am looking for a way to open these links from the History page in new tab by default. That is to say, I want to do this without having to right-click on the link and then select 'Open in new tab'.

Is there a way to change the default behavior of these links in the History page, or perhaps a Chrome Extension that would allow for more options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always hold Ctrl while clicking, which will open the history entry in a new tab in the background, or hold Ctrl+Shift while clicking, which will open the history entry in a new tab and focus it right away. That works with almost any link and also with the links in the History tab.

It's not precisely what you asked for, but it's relatively quick and much faster than right-clicking and selecting 'Open in new tab', so I thought I would mention this simple "solution" that works out of the box.

Comment: Yup this works! Just hold ctrl when click the links to open it in a new tab.

Comment: I guess this is easy enough to do. THanks!

Comment: @KalamalkaKid You're welcome! 